# SQL result set needs pivot display within asp.net/mvc3 webgrid or raw html table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the cleanest way to transform/pivot the following result set (top - raw data) and display/create in another view in a webgrid or html table (bottom - % of data) using razor?

Hotels are going to be dynamic (added all the time).  Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try the below?

```
SELECT  Region,
        HotelA
      , HotelB
      , HotelC
FROM    ( SELECT   Hotel ,region
                  , cast(hotelregioncount as numeric(18,2))/cast(totalhotelcount as numeric(18,2)) A
          FROM      hoteltable
        ) p PIVOT ( SUM(A)
                    FOR hotel 
                      IN (HotelA,HotelB,HotelC)
                  ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is what you want to make the columns dynamic

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)                  
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t2.Hotel
                        FROM    hoteltable AS t2
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t2.Hotel
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query =
'SELECT  Region,
        ' + @cols + '
FROM    ( SELECT   Hotel ,region
                  , cast(hotelregioncount as numeric(18,2))/cast(totalhotelcount as numeric(18,2)) A
          FROM      hoteltable
        ) p PIVOT ( SUM(A)
                    FOR hotel 
                      IN (' + @cols + ')
                  ) AS pvt'                 

execute(@query)
```